# Optimal weighting in case of unknown noise variances

Tags: noise, estimation, covariance

Let's consider $n$ multiple measurements $x_i[j]$ of the same desired signal $s[j]$ but with different uncorrelated zero-mean additive noise $n_i[j]$ with different variances $\sigma_i^2$:

$$
x_1[j] = s[j] + n_1[j] \\
\cdots \\
x_n[j] = s[j] + n_n[j] \\
$$

If the variances are known, the optimal linear combination to estimate $s[j]$ is to apply an inverse-variance weighting:

$$
\hat{s}[k] = \sum_{i\in[1,n]}w_ix_i[j]\\
w_i = \frac{1/\sigma_i^2}{\sum_{k\in[1,n]}1/\sigma_k^2}
$$

How can I proceed if I have no a priori on the noise variance $\sigma_i^2$. Is there a way to get the covariance matrix of $n$ from from the covariance matrix of $x$ ? I have been working on this the all day and I feel like I'm missing something. Or the problem might be more complex than it seems ?

Thanks

Comment: "Is there a way to get this information from the covariance matrix ?"  What covariance matrix?  If you're using a Kalman filter, tell us.  If you mean the covariance matrix of the noise -- well, if you know that, you know the noise variance!

Comment: The only think that I can compute is the covariance matrix of $x$. It's the sum of the covariance of the signal $s$ plus the covariance of the noise $n$ plus the cross terms. I need to estimate the covariance of the noise from that. It should be a diagonal matrix. And no I didn't try to use a Kalman approach. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: If you know the $x_i[j]$  then you can compute the variances of the $n_{i}[j]$ by computing the covariance matrix of the $x_{i}[j]$. But make sure you subtract off the mean when ( which is $s[j]$ ) you're computing it. The diagonals of this covariance matrix are the variances of the $n_i[j]$.

Comment: The goal is to estimate $s$ in a better way than computing the mean of the $n$ signals. I'm not sure to understand your proposal. Removing the mean of the covariance matrix of $x$?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand what you were doing. Now I do.  Your problem is pretty well formulated in the statistics literature. Solving it, maybe not. But here is a useful link and lectures 24 and 25 cover your problem. Based on what I've read of his material, this author, Cosmo Shalizi, seems like a really good teacher. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't see any link in your comment. Cosmo Shalizi wrote several books so I'm not sure which lecture you refer to.